# Replace apostrophes in between brackets

Tags: php

I would like to replace " and ' for \" in string that is between { } in PHP using preg_replace().

So:

```
This is "some" {"text" : 'duudu', 'duuue' : "yey" }
```

Should be:

```
This is "some" {\"text\" : \"duudu\", \"duuue\" : \"yey\" }
```

Could you advice on that please?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, Stack Overflow is not a free code service ;-)

Comment: `preg_replace()` cannot detect wehther something is *between {}* if braces can be nested. Even cases like `{"oo" : "o{o"}` cannot be handled by `preg_replace()`.

Comment: if you're trying to create JSON code, PHP has a built-in function to do that `json_encode()`. Don't try to create json strings manually; it will lead to errors and security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I am writing parser script which uses dynamic parameter which sometimes is JSON. Because end-user can call the function embed into HTML- "some" is e.g. first function parameter and json code is the second. From DB perspective everything is fine but got an error when it goes to eval.

Comment: An another solution: `explode()` by `{` once (see the 3rd parameter), then you have two results in array. The result at left keep, the result at right explode by `}` once, so you have again two results, this from the left is the string in `{}`, so `str_replace` all `"` to `\"`. Start again for the result on the right (if it is possible to have more than one `{...}` blocks). You can do this recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_replace_callback to solve this problem. Consider following code:

```
$str = 'This is "some" {"text" : \'duudu\', \'duuue\' : "yey" } "and" {"some", "other"} "text"';
echo preg_replace_callback('~({[^}]*})~', function($m) {
       return preg_replace('~(?<!\\\\)[\'"]~', '\"', $m[1]);
    }, $str) . "\n";
```

#### Update: For the purists who may like pure regex based solution:

```
$repl= preg_replace('~(?<!\\\\) [\'"] (?! (?: [^{}]*{ [^{}]*} ) * [^{}]* $)~x',
                    '\"' , $str);
```

**Output:**

```
This is "some" {\"text\" : \"duudu\", \"duuue\" : \"yey\" } "and" {\"some\", \"other\"} "text"
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/PfGzxd